# MySQL + symphony querybuilder with paginator limit : wrong number of entities

Tags: mysql, symfony, query-builder, dql, paginator

My database : MySQL
Project : Symfony 6

Table structure :
1 article may have many comments
each article must have 1 article.

Steps :

```
1 - I can list my articles filtered by user roles.

2 - I can list my articles and their comments.

3 - I can use a paginator.
```

Problem: BUT when 1 article got 2 comments with the first version of the query, the limit of the paginator gets 2 rows containing the same article in both lines, with the first comment on line 1, and the second comment on line 2.
So my first page only contains the first article with two comments, instead of two articles with all their comments.

So I need to use a subquery.
Problem : with MySQL, we can't use limit inside a subquery.
The workaround is to use inner join instead...

For now I managed to create a (working I think) query :

```sql
SELECT *
FROM article AS a
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT id AS requestedId
  FROM article
  WHERE role_requis = 'PUBLIC_ACCESS'
  ORDER BY requestedId ASC
  LIMIT 2 OFFSET 1
) AS article
ON article.requestedId = a.id
LEFT JOIN comment
ON comment.article_id = article.requestedId;
```

From you though, is there any way to make it in a shorter way ?
And if not I'm struggling to convert this query into a symfony querybuilder or dql... even with the documentation.

Thank you if you answer and try to help

EDIT :

Manage to find another way without LIMIT and OFFSET here is the final SQL query I have to convert into queryBuilder or DQL :

```sql
SELECT filteredArticle.*, comment.*, user.*
  FROM (
    SELECT row_number() OVER (ORDER BY article.id) AS articleNumber, article.*
    FROM article
    WHERE article.role_requis IN ('PUBLIC_ACCESS')
    GROUP BY article.id
    ORDER BY article.id ASC)
    AS filteredArticle
LEFT JOIN comment ON comment.article_id = filteredArticle.id
JOIN user ON filteredArticle.auteur_id = user.id
WHERE (articleNumber >= 1 AND articleNumber <= 2);
```

`Where (articleNumber > 1 and articleNumber < 2) :`

*Explaination : 1 = (currentPageNumber * limit) - limitByPage + currentPageNumber and 2 = currentPageNumber * limitByPage*

1. It is generating a row number representing the selected article
   number in the subquery
2. Add the article columns (ordered, filtered)
3. Join article's autor and comments
4. limit the subquery based on the generated articleNumber

It's still missing the subrequest total filteredArticle number...

EDIT :

Managed to add the max subrequest records with a cross join... but it's duplicating the main subrequest...

```
SELECT filteredArticle.totalRecordsNumber, filteredArticle.articleNumber, filteredArticle.id AS articleId, filteredArticle.titre, filteredArticle.corps, filteredArticle.date AS articleDate, filteredArticle.role_requis, comment.id as commentID, comment.contenu, comment.date AS commentDate, comment.auteur_id as commentAuteurId, user.id as articleAuteurID
FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM (
        SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY article.id) AS articleNumber, article.*
        FROM article
        WHERE article.role_requis IN ('PUBLIC_ACCESS'))
        AS filteredArticleWithoutTotal
    CROSS JOIN (
        SELECT Max(articleWihSelectedRoles.recordsNumber)
        AS totalRecordsNumber
        FROM (
                SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY article.id)
                AS recordsNumber
                FROM article
                WHERE article.role_requis
                IN ('PUBLIC_ACCESS'))
                AS articleWihSelectedRoles)
        AS total)
    AS filteredArticle
LEFT JOIN comment ON comment.article_id = filteredArticle.id
JOIN user ON filteredArticle.auteur_id = user.id
WHERE articleNumber >= 1 AND articleNumber <= 2
ORDER BY filteredArticle.id;
```

Making another thread to convert in query builder ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I wrote in the main post with edits, I found a way to get all needed informations from the database to paginate withotu limit/offset

1. I'm generating a pseudo ID with row_number in the subquery to determine how many articles are fetched and use this number in a where close as limit.
2. I'm duplicating the query to get the max number of records there is in the subquery (to calculate how many page in the repository).
3. I get My X number of articles, their informations, their comments, their users, ... and the total number of articles in the subquery.

BUT : Doctrine doesn't support row_number() eather...

SO I ended up using knpPaginator :

```
 $result = [];

            $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('article');
                $query->andWhere($query->expr()->in('article.role_requis', Roles::getGrantedRoles($user)))
                ->leftJoin('article.comments', 'comments')
                ->leftJoin('article.auteur', 'articleAuteur')
                ->leftJoin('comments.auteur', 'commentAuteur')
                ->addSelect('articleAuteur')
                ->addSelect('comments')
                ->addSelect('commentAuteur')
                ->orderBy('article.id', 'ASC')
            ;

            $datas = $this->paginator->paginate(
                $query, 
                $currentPageNumber, 
                $limitByPage
            );
            
        $result['datas'] = $datas->getItems();

        $result['totalPagesNumber'] = ceil($datas->getTotalItemCount() / $limitByPage);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get one Article and one comment in the query then prepare a query based on your `Article` entity and join it with the `Comment` Entity. Then you can create a custom DQL function to use in your query to get only 1 comment record. Please read this [medium blog](https://medium.com/simform-engineering/how-to-create-custom-dql-function-symfony-84da7044c714) for practical configuration.

Comment: No, I want 2 articles with their comments. The return must contain 1 line by comment for the 2 requested articles. Ex : article 1, with its first comment with id:1. Article 1 and the second comment of article 1 with id:2. Article 2 with first comment of the article 2 with id:3 and article 2 with its second comment with id:4. So the entity manager create the two articles (merged because they got the same article.id) and 1 entity for each of their comments.

Comment: Why not showing Article list and then display it's comment in second column in table?
This is simple, Fetch all Articles with pagination and display in table view. In Twig, you can display comments via `foreach`. For example: `{% for comment in article.comments %} {{ comment }} {% endfor %}`
If your Article and Comment entity mapping is correct (One to Many) then it will display output.

Comment: Using view in symfony repository is not a good practice unfortunately...

That's what I'm doing in twig side, but if I want the repository paginator to work properly I need to get my 2 requested articles (filtered by the limit)
And their comments in the same result.

The entityManager will create those articles, link their comments using the article.id = comment.article_id.

Initially I was receiving article 1 comment 1, Article 1 comment 2. So the limit was set on the global result (articles + comments), not on the article number vefore joining their comments.

Comment: I understand just now what you asked for, you mean :

select * from (SELECT * FROM article as filtredArticles WHERE filtredArticles.role_requis IN ("PUBLIC_ACCESS","ROLE_USER","ROLE_ADMIN") ORDER BY filtredArticles.id ASC LIMIT 2 OFFSET 1) as article left join comment on article.id = comment.article_id;

Yeah it works, but now the dql version is still hard to find...